# HP Envy screen brightness gets stuck

Tags: laptop, power-management, brightness, hp-envy

Once in a while, the screen brightness stops responding to any reason, and stays on full brightness.

For those of you that have HP Envy, you know what this means: battery suicide.

The <kbd>FN</kbd>+* controls don't work. I also tried going in to power settings and adjusting all modes brightness to low wend of spectrum, after saving, it has no effect.

I suppose I could try rebooting as I always just put my laptop to sleep.

Anyone came across this?

Comment: I have the same problem with a HP Mini netbook. I know the F2 key is not broken so it seems to be a firmware or driver issue specific to HP. I'm running Windows 7 - what OS are you running?

Comment: i was running 7 also.... gotten rid of that laptop since and got a macbook pro..

Comment: In my case I noticed that I'd changed the monitor driver so I'v reverted it and I'm keeping an eye on whether the keys stop working again. I don't have the $$$ for a Mac (-:

Comment: Reverting to the original monitor driver did not work for me on my HP Mini.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with this. It had to do with the F2 key being broken, which caused the brightness level to ramp up and not come down.

Try to disable the F2 key in the registry. If the problem disappears, you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the ACPI-driver. Try installing the latest version. Check the changelogs of the new BIOS updates as well, and see if you find any fixed issues related to this.

Try to change the brightness from within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also came across the same problem with my laptop.

Initially I was able to control the brightness of the laptop but after updating it, I got stuck on maximum brightness and it is really very painful.

So to solve this problem follow these steps:

1. Right click on `my computer` and then click on `manage`.
2. Select `device manager`.
3. Click on `monitors`.
4. Select `generic PnP monitor`, click on this and a new window will open.
5. Now `enable the monitor` which is I don't know why it got disabled.

Now you can control the brightness by default buttons or in control panel also.

Comment: wow.. thanks for answering but you realize this question was from 6 years ago :)

Comment: Yeah,i answered it because i faced this same problem and i was unable to find a solution which can help me. So it may help someone.

Comment: good point. I don't have the laptop anymore so can't confirm if this helped me though :/